# Are there any Facebook integration frameworks that support Android and iOS on .NET?

Tags: c#, android, ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity (C#) to create an iOS and Android app that shall be integrated with Facebook. Have done some research if this is possible but have not find anything good.

I have looked into http://www.ifc0nfig.com/accessing-facebook-within-unity/ but this requires the user to paste a string from her browser into the app to authenticate, and seems only to work for desktop apps.

Can any one give me tips on frameworks or plugins to Unity that support iOS and Android and have easy login for the user?

The facebook functionality to be supported:

- Easy login
- Get user's friend list
- Post to wall
- Support iOS/Android

Edit: Just found Prime31's Social Network Plugin http://prime31.com/unity/docs/#socialAndroidDoc
Is this perhaps the best option or are there any free options that does fulfill my needs?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prime31's Social Network Plugin was the choice for us, and it works fine for both iOS and Android after some small modifications.

Comment: Prime31 is for $65, do i need to purchase it separately for ios and android?

Comment: Yes, there are two versions, one for android and one for ios. However the interfaces are the same so they are easy to integrate side by side.

Comment: thanks Jonas for your reply, this mean i have to spend $65 + $g5 if i am targeting ios as well as android :(

Answer (score 0):

You can check developer.facebook.com. I worked on a android application which is connected with facebook. I found every documentation i need at there.

Comment: I know there are ways of getting Android and iOS connected to facebook separately. I have previously connected an Android app to facebook using java. However, now I want a c# example (not objective-c or java) to support both iOS and Android at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I've re-visited this and now the user isn't required to copy and paste any access tokens, it's fully automatic. Check it out: http://www.ifc0nfig.com/accessing-facebook-unity-game-2/